# How to solve redundant linear systems in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Problem I'm trying to solve is as follows. I have some linear equations with redundancy -- Ax = s where A isn't squared but has more rows than columns. Any advice shall be appreciated.

Here is what I'd like to do as elegantly as possible. I have some matrix A with n rows and m columns; n >= m.

What I'd like to generate is square matrix B from A such that m rows are selected from A and B is regular matrix.

That way I'll get regular matrix and I can use numpy.linalg.solve to calculate the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) to calculate the least squares solution to your problem (i.e. you don't need to throw any data away as you are proposing in your question).

This will find the vector *x* which minimizes the distance *| s - Ax |*